# Restructure files in directory by date

Tags: macos, bash, shell, directory, command

Currently, I have this markup, folders are named accordingly:

```
YYYY
----DD-MM-YYYY
--------FILES
--------FILES
--------FILES
```

What I'd like to do, is rather than having a different folder for every date inside the year, I'd like to categorise them into month, and then dates, example:

```
YYYY
----MM
--------DD-MM-YYYY
------------FILES
------------FILES
------------FILES
```

So it would say something like this once completed:

```
2010
----May
--------01-05-2010
------------a.jpg
------------b.jpg
------------c.jpg
----June
--------06-06-2010
------------1.jpg
------------2.jpg
------------3.jpg
```

I don't have much of an idea of how to proceed, but here's what I've tried so far with no success:

```
#!/bin/bash
currentYear="2010"
DIR="/path/to/year/folder/$currentYear"
target=$DIR
cd "$DIR"

for folder in *; do
    if [[ -d $folder ]]; then
        # We are a directory, assume this is a date folder
        dateString="$folder"
        month=???
        if [ ! -d "$target/$month" ]; then
            mkdir "$target/$month"
        fi
        mv '$folder" "$target/$month"
    fi
done
```

The only thing I think I'm really stuck with, is how to get the nice 'month' name, as in: 01-11-2010 would need to get November from this state string

Also, would my other code work fine or have I got errors there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the month's name with `date -d yourdate +%B` (or the abbreviated name with `+%b`).
You need to format your date, `date` needs something like YYYYMMDD or YYYY-MM-DD. Since you only need the month, you can cheat a little.

```
#!/bin/bash
currentYear=2010
DIR="/path/to/year/folder/$currentYear"
target=$DIR
cd "$DIR"

for folder in *; do
    if [[ -d $folder ]]; then
        dateString=$folder
        month=$(date -d "2000${dateString:3:2}01" +%B)
        mkdir -p "$target/$month"    # no need to check if it exists already
        mv "$folder" "$target/$month"
    fi
done
```

Comment: It extracts a substring, like this: `${var:position:lenght}`